# How to count newlines within a file, but not counting lines that are just newlines?

Tags: c, file, newline, c99, fgets

In order to properly parse input, I need to be able to count the number of lines in a file. However, I do not want to count lines that are just newlines. To help with this, I created the following function:

```
int countLinesInFile(char *filename) {
  int newlines = 0;

  if (access(filename,F_OK) != -1)
    error("File not found",0);

  FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");

  int size = 256 * 4;
  char buffer[size];
  while ((fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),input)) != EOF) {
    printf("Read a string");
    if (buffer == "\n")
      continue;
    newlines++;
  }

  fclose(input);
  return newlines;
}
```

At the top of the file, I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

When I run the program and attempt to count the lines, it segmentation faults. Using valgrind, I can see the following:

```
==6632== Invalid read of size 4
==6632==    at 0x4EA8E6B: fgets (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so)
==6632==    by 0x402219: countLinesInFile (in [executable])
[other information about program, does not seem relevant]
==6632==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6632== 
==6632== 
==6632== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6632==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==6632==    at 0x4EA8E6B: fgets (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so)
==6632==    by 0x402219: countLinesInFile (in [executable])
[other information about program, does not seem relevant]
==6632==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6632==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6632==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6632==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6632==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6632== 
==6632== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6632==     in use at exit: 475 bytes in 16 blocks
==6632==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 3 frees, 3,075 bytes allocated
==6632== 
==6632== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6632==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6632==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6632==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6632==    still reachable: 475 bytes in 16 blocks
==6632==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6632== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6632== 
==6632== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6632== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I have attempted to put a line that says "printf("Reading file")" at the start of the while loop. This code does not execute, and I believe that the fgets is the problem. Unfortunately, I do not know what this problem is.

I have verified that the file I am trying to read does have the correct text in it, and is not empty.

Is the function that I have created the correct method of this task? If so, what problem could I be having? How could I avoid this problem in the future?

Update: This was really a stupid mistake on my part. I was running the program with Valgrind, which looks like it doesn't use the executable's directory, which meant it couldn't find the file. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Start by checking the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: `buffer == "\n"` And that is not the way to compare strings in C. Need to use `strcmp` or character comparison `buffer[0] == '\n'`

Comment: `fgets` does not return `EOF`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I checked the output of fopen, it says "file not found", despite the fact that there is a "stuff.br" (the name of the file being opened, I checked) in the same directory.

Comment: Does the file exist in the same directory as the executable file? When running in IDE It is often not the same directory. try specifying the full path to the file name. Also, if you are entering a file name from the user Are you removing newline?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, it does exist in the same directory as the executable. I'm not using the IDE, I'm using Vim+CMake+Gcc. I am removing newline from user input. I will try specifying the full directory path, however.

Comment: Perhaps you think that some recognition is wrong, but I have no way to confirm it.

Comment: For example, Please change to the following format and test it. `ls *.br` ... `./a.out stuff.br`... `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`...  `int count = countLinesInFile(argv[1]);`

Comment: If the file is definitely there, check the permissions to make sure you (or the user/group the program runs as, at least) are actually allowed to read it.  Also, do you need `access()`, or can you just check whether `fopen()` returned NULL (which you need to do anyway)?

Answer (score 1):

Two things: first, `fgets` returns `NULL` as soon as no more line could be read, not `EOF`. Hence, the condition should be `while(fgets(...) != NULL)` or short `while(fgets(...))`.
Second, `buffer == "\n"` compares two pointers to characters, i.e. two memory addresses are compared. And it is very unlikely that anything has the same memory address as string literal `"\n"`. Hence, compare characters, i.e. `buffer[0]=='\n'` or `buffer[0]!='\n'`.
And I think you could easily get rid of the `continue`-statement, such that the code looks like the following:

```
  while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),input)) {
    if (buffer[0] != '\n') {
      newlines++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I did this, but it continues to segfault. I think the problem is with the first call of fgets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to keep track of the file offset of your last `\n` and if the position of this `\n` == last+1 then don't increment.

Answer (score 0):

Function `fgets` returns a pointer value, or NULL on failure. EOF is (usually, unless you've changed it) defined as -1. They will never compare equal, which means you'll be calling fgets long after you should stop.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would mean it would output if I added a line that prints whenever it runs the loop, which I did try. Unfortunately, it did not. I think this means that the first fgets fails.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` restricts you to a predefined line length.  To get around that, you can use [POSIX-standard `getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

When counting lines, to skip empty lines you can simply discount anything that matches `"\n"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

...

long countLines( const char *filename )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        return( -1L );
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t bytes = 0UL;
    long lineCount = 0L;

    for ( ;; )
    {
        ssize_t result = getline( &line, &bytes, fp );
        if ( -1 == result )
        {
            break;
        }

        if ( strcmp( line, "\n" ) )
        {
            lineCount++;
        }
    }

    free( line );
    fclose( fp );

    return( lineCount );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");
```

should be

```
FILE *input;
input = fopen(filename,"r");
```

I don't believe that `fgets()` returns a newline or an EOF. It stops reading at the character before the newline and the next read will be the character after the newline or successive newlines.

You probably need to use a binary file reading function that will read the entire file at once and then parse out the lines. This will also handle the case of a text file that does not have an EOF at the end. Many don't

- Get the size of the file.
- Allocate a buffer to hold the entire file.
- Read the entire file into the buffer.
- Parse the buffer.

[C library function - fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)
[C File I/O and Binary File I/O](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)

Comment: What's wrong with `FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");`? "use a binary file reading function" why would a binary file reader be needed for a text file?

Comment: There is no merit in the two-line code.  Your beliefs about `fgets()` are wrong — specifically, it includes the newline in the data unless there isn't room for it.  It indicates EOF by returning a null pointer.  There's absolutely no need to read the entire file into a buffer.  You can do the job with three integers (last character, this character, overall count) and `getc()`.